# Segmented Control with Table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm looking to build this screen. There is a segmented control with a table underneath. The contents of the table changes with the segmented control.

I'm building the views programatically using Swift.

I'm wondering what is the best way to layout the views?

Currently I am creating two views, setting the frames and adding them as subviews. I'm finding the scrolling isn't working on the table though as I change tables so I don't know if it's laid out correctly.

I am updating the frame of the `UITableView` after I do `reloadData()` on the table.

[image]

Comment: Why are you updating the frame of the table view? Surely that doesn't change. Only the contents of the tableview change?

Comment: Create IBAction for Segment Controller and check index 0 or 1. If segment controller index 0 than reload tableview and display purticular array for index 0 same as index 1. Also check in cellForRowIndexPath of UItableview method segment controller index 0 or 1.

Comment: @Fogmeister do I not need to update the height of the frame based upon the content?

Comment: The frame should never change. The content size may change but the frame never changes. The scrolling comes into effect when the content size is bigger than the frame size.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: You shouldn't have to actually DO anything. Just change the contents of the table through the datasource and the table will update its content size automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The auto layout of this view should not need to change when tapping the segmented control (the layout of the screen is the same; segmented control centered and at the top of the view, table taking up the rest of the space below, etc.) When the segmented control is tapped, just call `reloadData` on your table. The tableView's dataSource methods (`cellForRowAtIndexPath` etc.) should use the selected index of the segmented control to determine what data to display.

Answer (score -1):

1.) Check if `scrollEnabled` is set to true

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
```

2.) If there are any UIViews covering the TableView